Course matching algorithm
I am working on a project where I need to match 500 students to 50 courses. Each student can register for up to 10 courses and ranks the courses they wish from 1 to 10. Each course has a different capacity of students it can take.
The objective is not to find the "best" solution but a "good" solution (if possible, that all students will be matched with at least the top 4 courses they requested).
Is there a method or algorithm to perform the matching?

Give each student $10. Charge $1 for each course (only on first iteration). Let each student decide, which courses they enroll in. Adapt the prices of each course according to how full they are (up or down). Repeat from the beginning (blank slate except course prices).

To me it seems the the objective is unclear. It's very simple to check whether all students can get their top 4 courses. Just count how many that registered for a specific course and compare with capacity. The interesting part comes when all can't get what they want. For that you need to define a criteria for calculating "how good" a distribution is. Example: What is best? a) A student gets rank 1 course but not rank 2, 3,4 or b) A student doesn't get rank 1 course but gets rank 2, 3,4. You need to assign some "value" to the individual situations in order to do any meaningful distribution.

The question is not how to check if all students can get their top 4 courses. It is how to optimize the allocation of all to choices to all 50 courses. It is a good idea to rank each preference (for example 400, 300 , 200 , 100,60,70,50,40,30,20) but the question is then how to get the best solution.

First thing to note is that your requirements are not always solvable: let's say that there are 4 courses that have a cap of 10 students, and all 500 students put these as their top 4 choices. You'll obviously not be able to guarantee that the students get their top 4 choices. You may not even be able to give students any of their choices at all. That being said, you can make the following guarantees:

Stability: We define a "stable" solution to be a matching such that no two students would prefer each others' courses to their own, and no student prefers a course that isn't empty to their own. One way to do this is a greedy matching: go through the students in an arbitrary order and give them their top choice. Another slightly more fair algorithm to this is to start out with a random matching, and iterate through, swapping any unstable positions.
Minimum-Weight: You can assign a weight to each of the student's ordered preferences (e.g. maybe a student's least preferred course is assigned 10, and his most preferred course is assigned 1). For something like this, I might choose something exponential, like 2^x, where x is the ordinal (i.e. x=1 for the most preferred course and x=10 for the least preferred), to heavily penalise assigning students courses far behind on their preferences. Then, you can perform the iterative algorithm to match them to their preferences (this time swapping any time it would reduce the weight), which would guarantee the weight being at a local optimum, or better yet, converting it into a linear programming problem and solving it with the simplex algorithm.

